# How should one comment an if-else structure?

Tags: coding-style, comments

Lets say you have:

```
if(condition) {
    i = 1;
} else {
    i = 2;
}
```

and you need to put comments explaining `if` and `else` blocks. What's the most readable way of doing it so someone can easily pick them up at first glance?

I usually do it like this:

```
//check for condition
if(condition) {
    i = 1;
} else {
    //condition isn't met
    i = 2;
}
```

which I find not good enough as comments are located at different levels, so at quick glance you would just pick up `if` comment and `else` comment would look like it belongs to some inner structure.

Putting them like this:

```
if(condition) {
    //check for condition
    i = 1;
} else {
    //condition isn't met
    i = 2;
}
```

doesn't look good to me either as it would seem like the whole structure is not commented (condition might be big and take multiple lines).

Something like that:

```
//check for condition
if(condition) {
    i = 1;
//condition isn't met
} else {
    i = 2;
}
```

would be probably the best style from comments point of view but confusing as a code structure.

How do you comment such blocks?

**PS.** I am not asking about refactoring this two lines of code, only about code style and comment formatting.

Comment: With all this text, the question is anything but quick :-)

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, I always wondered about that, too.

Comment: I think this should be re-opened - It is a question about coding style, which can be answered based on expertise.

Answer (score 40):

If it is needed to comment if else statements, I prefer to describe the case what made the code reach that point.
Especially in code with a high cyclomatic complexity

```
if (condition) { 
// User is taking a course at college x:
    i = 1;
} else { 
// User is not taking any course at college x:
    i = 2;
}
```

Comment: I like this... specifically the comment in the "else" block. Your condition should be clear, but depending on the length and complexity (especially nesting) of the code, the meaning of the "else" may not be obvious at all.

Comment: This wouldn't work if for example, you wanted to put some comment for `i = 2` as well inside the else block. It would look like both of them are for `i = 2` or both are for the `else` block.

Comment: @aandis You could indent the comment relating to `i = 2;` to differentiate. Although I think that in any real-world situation, the comment itself should leave little doubt about whether it refers to the condition or the first statement.

Comment: @aandis Or for that case you could put two comments separated by a single line. Vertical space should not be a problem since long or unclear methods should be refactored into smaller/clearer ones.

Answer (score 24):

Another option is:

```
if(condition) { //check for condition
    i = 1;
} else { //condition isn't met
    i = 2;
}
```

Comment: this is the option I like... unless the comments are really long, then you're screwed...... i get frustrated and delete the comments because the look ugly.

Comment: +1 Best solution in my opinion.

Comment: This is what I do.  If the comments are long then put a comment block above the conditional explaining the whole thing.

Comment: I like all comments start at the same position (at top level preferably). Having them all over the place is much harder to read to me.

Comment: To me, "Check for condition" isn't helpful, either in its own right or as a generic place-holder.  Comments MUST be helpful, and not just repeat the code, hence my preference (detailed below) of "Comment explaining what the condition is trying to determine"

Answer (score 15):

You should only only annotate if the code is not self explanatory. So make the if self explanatory. Like this perhaps

```
bool fooIsNotReallyGood = ....;

if(fooIsNotReallyGood) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

Comment: +1 I do my best to have my code understandable without comments

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what question is about.

Comment: @serg555:  You may not explicitly ask this question, but this is the answer all the same.  If you were using actual comments in your examples above, it would immediately be clear that it depends completely on what the specific comment related to.  An actual comment at the outer level, for example, might explain that when you have a particular graphics card installed a bug arises that is otherwise not a problem, so you do things differently based on that condition.  An inner comment might explain a particularly complex algorithm and how it's tied to that particular branch of the if statement.

Comment: This is fine in an ideal world of simple code. However, if the first block is long, it might no longer be as clear what the "else" block refers to (also in the case of nested ifs). He might also be cleaning up someone else's code that he'd rather not refactor. It's a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: @mmc - that's what I added the bool variable. All tests can be reduced to to a single variable. If you need multiple variables to reduce the test to improve readability and so be it. This works in all cases. If you think that some code is too complex then you should be able create a simple expression and it only needs to be done once to ensure that future readers can see how the test works. Also I cannot imagine any piece of code where you can't simplify the code. If the simplification results in performance issues - that's when you introduce complex code with copious comments.

Comment: This is a useful technique but it definitely does not eliminate the need for if/else comments in all situations.

Answer (score 10):

If the code is not already self-documenting, then I would structure it as follows:

```
if (someCondition) {
    // If some condition, then do stuff 1.
    doStuff1();
}
else {
    // Else do stuff 2.
    doStuff2();
}
```

But again, it doesn't make much sense if the code is already self-documenting. If you would like to add comments because of some complex condition like:

```
if (x == null || x.startsWith("foo") || x.endsWith("bar") || x.equals("baz")) {
    doStuff1();
}
else {
    doStuff2();
}
```

Then I would consider to refactor it as:

```
boolean someCondition = (x == null || x.startsWith("foo") || x.endsWith("baz") || x.equals("waa");

if (someCondition) {
    doStuff1();
} else {
    doStuff2();
}
```

Wherein the variable name `someCondition` *actually* summarizes the whole condition in a nutshell. E.g. `usernameIsValid`,  `userIsAllowedToLogin` or so.

Comment: I also prefer comment above else on the same tab level. I don't agree with not commenting code, if statement might be easy as `someCondition`, but inside its structure there are for example 300 lines and in this case NOT commenting else statement would be stupid, because you need to scroll 300 lines top and another 300 bottom..

Answer (score 6):

Comments are very much a personal thing, and (as can be seen by some of the earlier answers) generate as much debate as the code.

In simple cases, comments detract from the code.  But assuming a more complex condition, I prefer:

```
/*
** Comment explaining what the condition
** is trying to determine
*/
if ( condition )
{
    /*
    ** Comment explaining the implications
    ** of the condition being met
    */
    do_something();
}
else
{
    /*
    ** Comment explaining the implications
    ** of the condition not being met
    */
    do_something_else();
}
```

In any case, the comments must not just repeat the code.

Answer (score 5):

Go for self-commenting conditions,then additional comments aren't necessary.  Let's say the condition is that the maximum loan to value is reached.  This gives us:

```
if (maximumLoanToValueIsReached)
{
   i=1;
}
else
{
   i=2;
}
```

No need to specify when i=2 that the maximum loan to value hasn't been reached as that is self explanitory.  As an aside, I'd also rename `i` to something more meaningful.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't comment in those particular cases at all--the comments don't add any value over your already clear code. If you have a really complex condition that's difficult to read, I'd consider factoring it into a function (probably `inline`) with a very clean name of its own.

Answer (score 2):

`//condition isn't met` seems to be a useless comment. But in the case where such a comment is required I do it like this (C#):

```
//check for condition
if(condition) 
{
    i = 1;
} 
//some other condition
else 
{
    i = 2;
}
```

However, if the block is just if-else, than I would merge both comments before if.

For javascript I prefer

```
//check for condition
if(condition) {
    i = 1;
} else { //some other condition
    i = 2;
}
```

P.S. Seems there is as many opinions as there are people :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do my comments for if then statements, although I usually find it isn't needed. I like putting it in line with the if/else, and tabbed to the same spot

```
if ( condition )    //if above the bar
{
    i = 0;
    k = 1;
}
else                //else if below
{
    i = 1;
    k = 2;
}
```

Comment: I like this method of doing things. It may take up more space but it makes it absolutely clear what is covered in a loop/if statement.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single answer - different people will have different opinions about what is *most* readable. However, I think there is agreement that the comments should actually add value to the (otherwise self-explanatory) code, and that the commenting style should be consistent.

The way I handle comments for not immediately self-explanatory conditions is like this:

```
  // If the condition for a local tree imbalance is met,
  // juggle the immediate nodes to re-establish the balance.
  // Otherwise, execute a global balancing pass.
  if ( somewhat muddled condition )
  {
     ...code...
  }
  else // Tree is in local balance
  {
     ... more code...

  } // if/else (tree locally imbalanced)
```

The comment on the final '}' exists primarily to give the end of the condition more visual weight, to make reading through the source easier.

Answer (score 1):

The variables are important, not the conditions themselves.

```
if condition: # <condition dependent variable> was <predicated>
  dosomething()
elif othercondition: # <othercondition dependent variable> <predicated>
  dootherthing()
else: # <all variables> <not predicated>
  doelsething()
```

Answer (score -3):

You may extract `if-else` code to methods and name them properly:

```
function main() {
  checkForCondition(condition);
  conditionIsNotMet(condition);
}

function checkForCondition(boolean condition) {
  if (condition) {
    i = 1;
  }
}

function conditionIsNotMet(boolean condition) {
  if (!condition) {
    i = 2;
  }
}
```

In such a trivial case this seems like an overkill, but imagine having more than one line per `if-else` branch.

Comment: Lol, in such case isn't it better to do something like this?

    if (condition)
      conditionIsMet();
    else
      conditionIsNotMet();

Comment: There are many problems with this code. First, the "either/or" relationship between your two functions (the fact that always only one of them will take effect) is obscured in `main()`. You have to look up the actual statements in several places, and don't immediately see if there could be any side effects. You're also checking the condition twice, which is potentially expensive. And it adds the overhead of two function calls, which will probably also want to return something back to `main`. — I know the answer is old, but thought it couldn't hurt to back up the downvotes in some way.